# Use "stacked" design in Seaborn Factorplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I use a seaborn Factorplot (kind=bar) to represent in total 6 bars in 2 "categories" (3 bars for each category). I would like to enhance this factorplot by using the stacked design, that is I want to represent each bar by its "subcomponents".
I know that this is possible for barplot but is it also possible for factorplot?

Comment: show some code that demonstrates the structure of your data and whay you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

Randy Zwitch [explains](http://randyzwitch.com/creating-stacked-bar-chart-seaborn/) how to create a stacked bar chart in seaborn.

The solution is to think of a stacked bar chart as multiple, overlaying, plots on the same graph so the bottom segment of the bars are at the front and obscure the lowest parts of the subsequent segments.

To quote from his blog :

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

#Read in data & create total column
stacked_bar_data = pd.read_csv("C:\stacked_bar.csv")
stacked_bar_data["total"] = stacked_bar_data.Series1 + stacked_bar_data.Series2

#Set general plot properties
sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_context({"figure.figsize": (24, 10)})

#Plot 1 - background - "total" (top) series
sns.barplot(x = stacked_bar_data.Group, y = stacked_bar_data.total, color = "red")

#Plot 2 - overlay - "bottom" series
bottom_plot = sns.barplot(x = stacked_bar_data.Group, y = stacked_bar_data.Series1, color = "#0000A3")


topbar = plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,fc="red", edgecolor = 'none')
bottombar = plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,fc='#0000A3',  edgecolor = 'none')
l = plt.legend([bottombar, topbar], ['Bottom Bar', 'Top Bar'], loc=1, ncol = 2, prop={'size':16})
l.draw_frame(False)

#Optional code - Make plot look nicer
sns.despine(left=True)
bottom_plot.set_ylabel("Y-axis label")
bottom_plot.set_xlabel("X-axis label")

#Set fonts to consistent 16pt size
for item in ([bottom_plot.xaxis.label, bottom_plot.yaxis.label] +
             bottom_plot.get_xticklabels() + bottom_plot.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(16)
```