# subplots from a multiindex pandas dataframe grouped by level

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, multi-index, subplot

How I do multiple plot from a multi-indexed pandas DataFrame based on one of the levels of the multiindex?

I have results from a model with different technologies usage in different scenarios, the results could look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(12,4)),columns=[2011,2012,2013,2014])
df['scenario']=['s1','s1','s1','s2','s2','s3','s3','s3','s3','s4','s4','s4']
df['technology'=['t1','t2','t5','t2','t6','t1','t3','t4','t5','t1','t3','t4']
dfg=df.groupby(['scenario','technology']).sum().transpose()
```

dfg would have the technologies employed each year for each scenario. I would like to have a subplot for each scenario sharing the legend.

If I simply use the argument subplots=True, then it plots all the possible combinations (12 subplots)

```
dfg.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,subplots=True)
```

Based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386870/pandas-plotting-with-multi-index) I got closer to what I was looking for.

```
f,a=plt.subplots(2,2)

fig1=dfg['s1'].plot(kind='bar',ax=a[0,0])

fig2=dfg['s2'].plot(kind='bar',ax=a[0,1])

fig2=dfg['s3'].plot(kind='bar',ax=a[1,0])

fig2=dfg['s3'].plot(kind='bar',ax=a[1,1])

plt.tight_layout()
```

but the result is not ideal, each subplot has a different legend...and that makes it quite difficult to read. There must be an easier way to do subplots from a multiindexed dataframes... Thanks!

EDIT1: Ted Petrou proposed a nice solution using seaborn factorplot but I have two issues. I already have a style defined and I'd rather not use the seaborn style (one solution could be change the parameters of seaborn). The other problem is that I wanted to use a stacked bar plot, which require considerable [extra tweaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918228/use-stacked-design-in-seaborn-factorplot). Any chance I can do something similar with Matplotlib?

Comment: You can use seaborn plotting functions without the seaborn style if you import seaborn this way: `import seaborn.apionly as sns`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my opinion it's easier to do a data analysis when you 'tidy' up your data - making each column represent one variable. Here, you have all 4 years represented in different columns. Pandas has one function and one method to make long(tidy) data from wide(messy) data. You can use `df.stack` or `pd.melt(df)` to tidy your data. Then you can take advantage of the excellent seaborn library which expects tidy data to easily plot most anything you want.

#### Tidy the data

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['scenario', 'technology'], var_name='year')
print(df1.head())

  scenario technology  year     value
0       s1         t1  2011  0.406830
1       s1         t2  2011  0.495418
2       s1         t5  2011  0.116925
3       s2         t2  2011  0.904891
4       s2         t6  2011  0.525101
```

### Use Seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.factorplot(x='year', y='value', hue='technology', 
               col='scenario', data=df1, kind='bar', col_wrap=2,
              sharey=False)
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.

Comment: Tidy the data is indeed a good suggestion! I am a bit reluctant to use seaborn because I have several figures in the report and I want all of them to have the same style (colors, fontsizes...). is there a way to do the same with matplotlib/pandas? Or, change the seaborn style parameters so it matches a particular matplotlib style?

Comment: Note that more recent versions throw UserWarning: The `factorplot` function has been renamed to `catplot`. I cannot edit the answer as the edit queue is full

Answer (score 0):

Actualizing the answer - The factorplot function has been renamed to catplot(). Here's a link to [Seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/archive/0.11/whatsnew.html?highlight=factorplot).

Thus you want to use it instead:

```
sns.catplot(x='year', y='value', hue='technology',
              col='scenario', data=df1, kind='bar', col_wrap=2,
              sharey=False)
```